# Bubblesort in LabVIEW formula node

Tags: formula, labview, bubble-sort

I'm trying to create a histogram of an image. I was thinking to first bubblesort the array of the pixels so every number is sorted from low to high.

Then its easier to count how many times a specific value of a pixels appears. And then later I can put it in a graph.
[image]

But it always gives an error then I don't understand.
[image]

I also want to make everything with the formula node instead of just blocks.

Visual:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlmW2.png

Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91TbS.png

Comment: Why don't you add a snippet of your code (in the VI's menu: Edit->Create Snippet from selection) so other users can drag drop the code into LabVIEW?

Comment: If you have access to the full development system, you might check out the "Unique Numbers and Multiplicity.vi", on the Mathematics->Polynomial palette.

Comment: Is this an exercise? LabVIEW has a histogram function already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code numbers is a scalar not an array.

Besides that the formula node does not maintain state, you'll need a feedback node to get history. Is there any reason why do you want to use the formula node instead of native LabVIEW code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the two nested LabVIEW for loops, you are iterating through your array inside the formula node so you don't need to do it with the loops.